# Show $\mathbb Q(u,i)\neq\mathbb Q(u)$ where $u$ is a root of $t^4-3t^2+4$

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials, galois-extensions

I try to show that $\Bbb Q(u,i)$ with u root of the polynomial $t^4-3t^2+4$ cannot be reduced to $\Bbb Q(u)$, that is, that $i$ does not belong $\Bbb Q(u)$, but I have not been able to prove it and I would like someone to help me. So far I have tried something that does not seem to be successful: Suppose that I can be written as a linear combination of ${1, u, u ^ 2, u ^ 3}$ and, through operations on the equation $x^2+1=0$, arrive at a contradiction with respect to the coefficients, and then demonstrate the irreducibility of the polynomial $f$ in $\Bbb Q(i)$ to see that the degree of $[\Bbb Q(u,i):\Bbb Q(i)] = 4$.

PS:I am new to this page and I am learning, so I hope you take it into consideration. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I took your totally unhelpful and downvote-magnet title ("Somebody could help me?") and replaced it with a useful one. See how easy that was? Just do that in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Solving
$$u^4-3u^2+4=0$$
gives
$$u^2=\frac{3\pm\sqrt{-7}}2$$
and
$$u=\sqrt{\frac{3\pm\sqrt{-7}}2}.$$
As an element of the number field $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-7})$, $u^2$ has norm
$4$ so we might hope that $u^2$ is a square there. But instead we find that
$$\frac{3\pm\sqrt{-7}}2=-\left(\frac{1\mp\sqrt{-7}}2\right)^2.$$
So 
$$u=\pm i\frac{1\mp\sqrt{-7}}3$$
which means that $i$ lies in the Galois closure $K$ of $\Bbb Q(u)$.

We should be in luck if we find that $K$ has degree $4$ over $\Bbb Q$. Let's
fix one of the four values for $u$, so suppose
$$2u=i+\sqrt7.$$
Then
$$4u^2=6+2i\sqrt 7$$
so
$$2u^2-3=i\sqrt7.$$
Therefore
$$2u(2u^2-3)=i\sqrt7(i+\sqrt7)=-\sqrt7+7i$$
and then
$$2u(2u^2-3)+2u=8i.$$

Comment: +1
Does this means I was wrong and $Q(u,i)=Q(u)$ ?
Thanks

Comment: I think (unless I've made an error) that I have shown that $i\in Bbb Q(u)$. @matematicaenfurecida